# Resource namespace Issue in Rails Engine with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm having a problem where I've successfully registered a resource in ActiveAdmin, but I can't create or update any records. I think it's due to a namespacing issue. Can I override it using an option while registering the resource?

I'm building a Rails Engine that registers AA resources from within the engine. I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Define-a-resource-inside-an-engine).

My engine contains lib/admin/myengine/myresources.rb

```
if defined?(ActiveAdmin)
  ActiveAdmin.register Myengine::Myresource do
  end
end
```

In the test/dummy app, the relevant schema looks like:

```
create_table "myengine_myresources", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When I run the dummy app server, I successfully navigate to http://localhost:3000/admin/myengine_myresources and click 'New Myengine Myresource'

I type in a name and click 'Create Myresource', but it treats the request as if I've submitted blank attribute values.

The server log shows:

```
Started POST "/admin/myengine_myresources" for ::1 at 2015-12-02 11:13:52 -0800
Processing by Admin::MyengineMyresourcesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"stuff", "myresource"=>{"name"=>"Arbitrary Name"}, "commit"=>"Create Myresource"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (190.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 199.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

My working theory is that the params need to be inside :myengine_myresource rather than just :myresource.

Any ideas on how to get that working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one workaround:

```
if defined?(ActiveAdmin)
  ActiveAdmin.register Myengine::Myeresource do
    controller do
      def permitted_params
        params[:myengine_myresource] = params.delete :myresource
        params.permit(myengine_myresource: [:my, :list, :of, :accepted, :params])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is actually is InheritedResources issue, and in [this discussion](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3161) described another workaround, and [this pull request](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/pull/404) should completely fix this issue